# Divide-and-conquer find max sub array problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, segmentation-fault, big-o

I have read about the divide and conquer approach and its efficiency to solve problems. Find the maximum subarray is the example described in the book. When I tried to implement it with the C++ language, it caused a segmentation fault error.

```
//this is for finding the max sub array if it is in the middle it is correct
Max_Array Find_Crossing_SubArray(int * arr , int low , int hight)
{
    int sumLeft = 0,sumRight=0 , sumTemp = 0 , mid  = (low+hight)/2 ;
    Max_Array returned = {nullptr,0,0,0,0};
    for(int j = mid ; j >= 0 ; j--)
    {
        sumTemp +=arr[j] ;
        if(sumLeft < sumTemp)
        {
            returned.low = j;
            sumLeft = sumTemp ;
        }
    }

    sumTemp = 0;
    for(int j = mid+1 ; j < hight ; j++)
    {
            sumTemp += arr[j] ;
            if(sumRight < sumTemp)
            {
                returned.hight = j ;
                sumRight = sumTemp ;
            }
    }
    returned.sum =sumRight + sumLeft;
    returned.t = arr + returned.low;
    returned.size = returned.hight - returned.low ;

    return returned;
}
int mid;

//the function that throws the error+++++++++++  

Max_Array Find_Max_SubArray(int* arr, int low , int hight) 
{
    if(low == hight)
    {
        Max_Array r = {arr,low,low,1,arr[low]};
        return r;
    }
    else
    {
        Max_Array rightArray,leftArray,middleArray;
         mid = (low+hight)/2 ;
        
        rightArray = Find_Max_SubArray(arr,mid+1,hight);
    
       
        leftArray = Find_Max_SubArray(arr,low,mid);

        middleArray = Find_Max_SubArray(arr,low,hight);

        if(rightArray.sum >= leftArray.sum && rightArray.sum >= middleArray.sum)
            return rightArray;
        else if(leftArray.sum >= rightArray.sum && leftArray.sum >= middleArray.sum)
            return leftArray;
        else
            return middleArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code gives the error and what are the input parameters? Do you have a call stack with the list of local variables at the time of the crash?

Comment: Looks like two problems here: 1. You mixed up whether you are considering [low, high] or [low, high) inside the functions. `if(low == hight)` would need to be `if(low + 1 == hight)`. 2. You have a typo that makes this infinitely recurse. `middleArray = Find_Max_SubArray(arr,low,hight);` should be `middleArray = Find_Crossing_SubArray(arr,low,hight);`

Comment: Another typo: `for(int j = mid ; j >= 0 ; j--)` should be `for(int j = mid ; j >= low ; j--)`. Even though that function is technically correct without fixing it, the algorithm would take O(n^2) time instead of O(n*log(n)).

Comment: **Protip:** You should add the structure of `Max_Array` by editing the question.

Comment: Also `rightArray = Find_Max_SubArray(arr,mid+1,hight);` should be `rightArray = Find_Max_SubArray(arr,mid,hight);` if you're going for [low, high). In any case, you should pick either [low, high] or [low, high) at the very start and be consistent with it, because right now it is inconsistent, causing errors. I highly recommend [low, high) as it is a standard practice in programming.

Comment: @shananton thank you a lot you really help me your notes are very helpful tnx a lot